# sharepoint custom list: multi-line field content is blank when person/group field has multiple values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, custom-lists

I have a custom list with the following fields:

- **Title**: Single line of text
- **Description**: Multiple lines of text
- **Remarks**: Multiple lines of text
- **Recipient**: Person or Group

Whenever I input two or more people in the **Recipient** field, in **View Item** page (*Display* form), contents of **Description** and **Remarks** becomes blank/empty.
Contents are displayed okay on the main view of custom list, and in EDIT mode.

If I input a single person only in the **Recipient** field, the contents for **Description** and **Remarks** are displayed in *Display* form.

Note: **Recipient** field is set to accept multiple values. I'm using Sharepoint 2013.

I am new to Sharepoint and I'd like to know a way on how to troubleshoot/debug this matter. Or are the multi-line fields somehow connected to the person field? Or any setting that I need to setup? How can I check?

I tried to search but I found no same situation as far.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no customization in Display form, it should work fine. If it works for Single User in Recipient, It should work for multiple users too.

For further troubleshooting, You can create a test list and create same type of columns in it. Then see if the Display form works fine in that test list. It will let you know if the issue is related to the specific list or it's generic. You can then narrow down your troubleshooting options based on this result.

Comment: Hi Anit! Thanks for your comment. I have not customized the Display form. It's the default form when we create a custom list. I also already created a test list, very basic, with same fields, and the result is the same.

Comment: Hi Anne..I don't have idea of your SharePoint Setup, so I'm not entirely sure why this issue is occurring. 
For further troubleshooting I can only suggest to inspect the HTLM source code of the Multiple Line of Text fields in DisplayForm to see if there is corresponding HTML code in the page and any CSS is causing it not to be visible. You can check using developer tool if there is any script error or you can try re-ordering the columns for rendering like multiple lines of text first, then title and other combinations.

Comment: Hi Anit.. I already tried re-ordering columns but still same problem.. Checked also the css, or any javascript not functioning.. found nothing different. In SPD, I can only see Sharepoint automated tags on DisplayForm aspx, and have no idea how to check the actual code, or variables.. Is there a way I can debug this through Visual Studio? I've been working on this for days already.. I appreciate your help Anit.. thank you..